# Vector Initialization in cpp

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

How to initialize a vector of size 26 by English Alphabet?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just do it.

Comment: If you just want to limit yourself to [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) encoding (which arguably is the only one most programmers will ever use, and its "extension" UTF-8), then it's *extremely* easy in C++, with the [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) function.

Comment: If you initialize it at once, it will easily fit on one line...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can. You can easily do this with `std::iota` and the ASCII character sequencing starting at letter `A`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> alphabet(26);
    std::iota(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end(), 'A');

    for (const auto& i : alphabet)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To know this works, you have to know the execution character encoding that the compiler transcodes 'A' to and that by incrementing `char` over the range produces the desired sequence with `char` values that are valid in that encoding. Yes, it does work for encodings similar to ASCII, for the English alphabet. The first is laissez faire; the second is overfit.

Comment: A small consult: this won't work with Spanish alphabet, right?

Comment: @Xam Technically no, this solution exploits the fact that ASCII character encodings are ordered for the English language alphabet.  To get the Spanish characters like ň (eňe) you will need to jump around to different ASCII codes. It's possible that there are different encodings that it would work for, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Pedantically, "initialization" is creating an object such that at no place is it accessible without it holding its intended value,

```
std::vector<char> englishAlphabetUpper({ 
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 
    'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'});
```

Not sure why you want a vector for a well-defined value like the English alphabet as uppercase letters. That's an immutable concept, so an immutable object like

```
const char englishAlphabetUpper[] = {
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 
    'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
```

should serve better.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>
static const char* sAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
std::vector<char> vAlphabet(sAlphabet, sAlphabet+26);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a compolement to Tom Blodget's answer. Here is another syntax for initializing the vector. I think this was introduced in C++11. I prefer this syntax. :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<char> U = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

    for (int i = 0; i < U.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << U[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << "\b\b." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```